# sparql/snorql example, first step

Tags: sparql

I am struggling a bit to understand how SPARQL works. Can someone please tell me how I for instance find name and place of all persons who have last name Churchill on
http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

Answer (score 0):

This gets the full names:

```
SELECT ?x ?name WHERE {
  ?x foaf:surname "Churchill"@en.
  ?x foaf:name ?name
}
```

People don't have a “place” as such. What would that be anyway? They may have birth and death places and the like.